# Parse - unable fetch and update column from Installation class

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to fetch data from `Parse.Installation` class using the constraint `query.equalTo("installationId", uuid);` then, when I want to update the rows that I got in the success callback; however, I was no able to do so, I don't receive any errors so far.

I am executing it from the cloud code.

Here is the code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("updateInstallationClass", function(request, response) {

var uuid = request.params.uuid;
var userID = request.params.userID;
  var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend(Parse.Installation);
        var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
        query.equalTo("installationId", uuid);
        query.first({useMasterKey:true},{
          success: function(object22) {
            // Successfully retrieved the object.
              object22.set("userID3", userID);
              object22.save(null, {useMasterKey:true});
             console.log("userID3", userID);
            console.log('success ', object22);
          },
          error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
          }
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update Parse.Installation entries you must call the following function before ***ParseObject.save()***:

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

**Result code:**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("updateInstallationClass", function(request, response) {

    var uuid = request.params.uuid;
    var userID = request.params.userID;
    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend(Parse.Installation);

    var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
    query.equalTo("installationId", uuid);
    query.first({useMasterKey:true},{
        success: function(object22) {
            // Successfully retrieved the object.

            // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
            Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
            // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

            object22.set("userID3", userID);
            object22.save(null, {useMasterKey:true});
            console.log("userID3", userID);
            console.log('success ', object22);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
});
```

### Edit 1:

Call `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` at the first line, Before execute the query.
Your installation table has no read permission.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("updateInstallationClass", function(request, response) {

    // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    var uuid = request.params.uuid;
    var userID = request.params.userID;
    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend(Parse.Installation);

    var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
    query.equalTo("installationId", uuid);
    query.first({useMasterKey:true},{
        success: function(object22) {
            // Successfully retrieved the object.

            object22.set("userID3", userID);
            object22.save(null, {useMasterKey:true});
            console.log("userID3", userID);
            console.log('success ', object22);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
});
```

### Edit 2:

To save a pointer values, you must create new instance of the class and assign the objectId.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("updateInstallationClass", function(request, response) {

    // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    var uuid = request.params.uuid;
    var userID = request.params.userID;
    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend(Parse.Installation);

    var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
    query.equalTo("installationId", uuid);
    query.first({useMasterKey:true},{
        success: function(object22) {
            // Successfully retrieved the object.

            var user = new Parse.User();
            user.set("objectId", userID);
            object22.set("userID3", user);

            object22.save(null, {useMasterKey:true});
            console.log("userID3", userID);
            console.log('success ', object22);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
});
```

### Edit 3:

Replace:

```
var user = new Parse.User();
user.set("objectId", userID);
```

With:

```
var UserObj = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var user = new UserObj();
user.id = userID;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried it, but it didn't work. Even, I can't see any success/error message on the logs!

Comment: change the  `alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);` with `console.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);`

Comment: The error is certainly coming from here >  object22.set("userID3", userID); because `userID3` is a pointer, but I don't know how to save pointer values!

Comment: Thanks David, I've tried `var user = new Parse.User();` even I just done a copy-paste of your second edit, and nothing works so far!

Comment: @HamzaL. I used to construct new parse user like "Edit 3".

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked finally, EDIT2 worked for me, I had only some issue from my side that's why it didn't worked before ;) +1